# Lagrange interpolating polynomial

Tags: interpolation

How can one find
$$ L[x_0,x_1,..,x_n;\frac{1}{x+a}]?$$
The original problem asks for $$ L[x_0,x_1,..,x_n;\frac{x^{n+1}}{x\pm 1}]$$
I know there is a formula for $[x_0,x_1,..,x_n,\frac{f(x)}{a-x}]$, but I suppose it does not help.

Comment: You mean "other than by plugging $f(x)=1/(x+a)$ into the Lagrange interpolation formula? Not clear what answer you expect.

Comment: I think there has to be a quick method for finding the coefficients of the polynomial without having to use the general formula.